# Programming Language Abstraction in Scala/Java

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, types, abstraction

I am currently writing a program using matlab in scala (via the matlabcontrol API). I want to achieve a programming language independent solution, so I can use some algorithms in Scala and some in Matlab.
The program works already (as far as I tested it) but I am also interested in abstraction so that I can exchange modules using scilab or other languages.

To understand the problem in detail I show you the ImageReader class:

```
trait ImageReader {
  def readImage(path:String):Any
}

object Matlab_ImageReader extends ImageReader {
  def readImage(path:String):Any = {
     proxy.eval("image = imread('"+ path + "');"
     return "image"
  }
}
```

The idea is, that I want to treat the return value as a reference to the language object I use. I will use Scala only as a controler, working with references and thereby implementing a partwise object-oriented solution for a complicated piece of matlabcode.

Now I also want to exchange parts of the code and give other developers a possible entrypoint for implementing their own solution for example in Scala. 
The problems are:

1. How to return a concrete and mutual Datatype, so I can use the method knowing I will always have the same return-type?
2. How to get a reference to a value in Scala? It would help me a lot as I may be able to abstract it this way.

I am sorry for the vague question, but I do not really know how to explain my exact problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should look at [Lightweight Modular Staging](http://scala-lms.github.io/) and [Scala Virtualized](https://github.com/tiarkrompf/scala-virtualized/wiki).

Comment: It seems like a very good approach for what Iam searching for. Ill try to get deeper into that - thanks a lot :)